# "sqlite Database is locked" Exception occurs while using it in more than one process

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using sqlite database,
one sqlite database file accessed from 2 process simultaneously so it throws error:

> "Database is locked".

I used `Lock(){ /*sqlite addition*/ }` for all insert or update operations. Is there any way to find out is sqlite DB file is being used in another process or is it open in another process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite3 and multiple processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063438/sqlite3-and-multiple-processes)

Comment: i read the link which you gave but while using it in c# .net.
My code is like
Open Connection,
// insert or update query
// Executenonquery()

at this moment it throws exception. so i want to check it here only how can i check with existing connection.
because that code is generic so connection object is different for different call.
so i want to check it there only

Comment: Hey could you please tell me solution for this i am stuck on it from last one week.
I want to access same database file in 2 process concurrently. 
how should I lock that database file in different process.

Comment: I want to do it in c#.net and sqlite.netdll

Comment: Have you tried this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17592858/95008
Or alternatively this: http://www.techcoil.com/blog/my-experience-with-system-data-sqlite-in-c/