# docker-compose, mount live database from host (live sync)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My goal is to have a program running on the `host` machine that writes data to a `sqlite` db that is then transferred (mounted) to a docker-compose running Grafana.

It is possible to do this with the following configuration

```yaml
grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    networks:
      - backend
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - ../database/database.sqlite:/home/grafana/database.sqlite
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./grafana/datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  grafana_data:
    external: true
```

However, this will only mount the DB at the time of creation, any new changes written to the `db` will not be reflected on the container.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The bind mount is supposed to reflect writes on both the container and the host (and this is most true on native Linux where they are literally the same file).  You might find a standalone relational database like PostgreSQL to be a little easier to interact with and a little less fragile, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried playing around with that, but never got it to work. Do you have a working example by any chance?

Comment: The [Docker samples](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) include several database-setup examples, as do a significant fraction of the [tag:docker] questions.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I'll revisit the bind mount and if I come with the solution I'll share it everyone. Thanks for your input

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063768) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10325683) StackOverflow questions. Having multiple concurrent connections to an SQLite database is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @ItaiSteinherz, the host will be the only one writing to the DB, the docker image only needs `ro` access and they can wait for a `lock` without any issues (display some metrics on Grafana can be deferred). Going to go over your links in a moment as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to mount a live `db` (in this case I'm using `Sqlite` for some dashboard visualization in `Grafana`. The `docker-compose.yml` is as follows:

The sqlite db will exist, be written and read from the `host machine`, this in turn will be `binded` to the docker container.

```yaml
grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    networks:
      - backend
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: database/database.sqlite
        target: /home/grafana/database.sqlite # needs to be absolute
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./grafana/datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  grafana_data:
    external: true
```

Keep in mind that if you're using `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`, the `docker container` will not reflect the changes until the journal is closed.